# Moving method to another class in Java

Tags: java, class

I have two classes: ID3 and Node as shown below:

```
class Node {
    public Vector kept;
    public Node[] children;
    public Node parent;

    public Node() {
        kept = new Vector();
    }
}
```

and in the other class (`ID3`) I have a method:

```
public void sTree(Node node, int heuristic) {
    int noOfIn = noOfAttributes - 1;
}
```

and I wish to move the `sTree()` method to the other class (`Node`), since it is related to the tree. However, the variable noOfAttributes, etc are defined in the ID3 class (global) and so aren't found in the Node class if I move this method (I need them in the ID3 class due to other methods so I can't remove them from ID3 and put them to Node class). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are creating a new variable I don't see how that would be a problem. You have not given a complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can use `interface` and put sTree method in it.. Implement this interface on classes where you need this method..

Comment: From the code you have shown `noOfEx` is a local variable, so in what way is it part of ID3 class?

Comment: sry I took a mistake please see edit

Comment: Why is it appropriate to move the method, but not move the variable on which it depends?  I suspect that either you should move both, or neither.  But I really don't have enough context to say that confidently.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static variable in your ID3 class and call it in Node. In ID3 create a static variable like so:

```
public static noOfEx;
```

Then set it in the ID3 class when applicable. To call it from Node just do

```
int noOfEx = ID3.noOfEx;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the shared data into a new class. Create a single instance of this class and pass it to every instance of `Node` and `ID3` which you create.

To make this process more simple, I suggest to create a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) for nodes and IDs. The factory knows all the building blocks and how to assemble them.

Don't forget: [Global variables are evil.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)